# How do I enable C++ styled comments in gcc while leaving ANSI enabled?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, comments

This has just come up as a question where I worked so I did a little digging and the answer is a ExpertsExchange one. So I hand you over to the original question asker, Manchung:

> I have a project written in pure C which is to be used in embedded system. So, I use pure C to minimize the code size.
>
> When I compile the project, I use the -ansi flag in order to make sure the code complies with the ANSI standard. However, the down side of using this ansi flag is that I am only allowed to use C styled comments (/*comments */). This is giving me a headache when I need to use nested comments.
>
> So, my question is: what switches/flags can I use to allow me to use C++ styled comments (// comments) while keeping the ANSI checking enabled at the same time?

Which pretty much sums my question up too.

Comment: The top voted answer to this question is no longer valid. I'd love to see a solution - in my case it's because I'm trying to enforce cross platform code compatibility between Windows and Linux. Windows requires mostly ANSI compliant code, but has c++ style comments in system headers.  And my Windows developers *will* use c++ style comments if I don't flag them as warnings (and it as an error). Enabling c++ comments in GCC seems to be the simplest answer.

Answer (score 30):

On recent releases of gcc, `-ansi` is documented as being the same as `-std=c89`. The new comment syntax is only available with the C99 standard, so `-std=c99` would allow it.

There is also `-std=gnu89`, which is the same as `-std=c89` but allowing all gcc extensions (including the C++-style comment syntax, which was a GNU extension long before it was added to the standard).

Also look at the `-pedantic` flag, which could give you some useful warnings.

References:

- http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C-Dialect-Options.html
- http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html

Comment: -std=gnu89 is probably the OP's best bet, -std=c99 has other consequences that may not be desirable.

Comment: -std=gnu89 worked for me, I was also looking for enhanced comments with largely ansi semantics.

Comment: The [docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html) says that -ansi option is equivalent to -std=c90, not to c89 (just to be "correct", even though those two seem to be synonymous again?)

Answer (score 19):

If you want to use C++ style comments merely because you want to comment out blocks, and get a headache about nesting /* ... */, you can use this technique:

```
#if 0
... code ...
#endif
```

which will actually also do the job.

Comment: Anything wrong with my answer? Please comment if you downvote. You cannot nest C-Style comments, and C++ style comments are not valid in C++89. This `#if 0` is pretty much the only way there to do it cleanly if you want to comment out *code*.

Comment: This is the BEST approach to this problem, IMHO.

Comment: This does not answer the question. It only avoids it.

Comment: @thomas  But I suspected that the questions real problem was commenting out code. And therefor I replied. My answer avoids the question because it tries to solve the assumed problem at the roots which is superior.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb And in doing so your answer does not answer the question everyone clicks on this link wanting to solve, and is much less general. So, no, it's not superior. It helps the OP, but does not help most people who click on the link later on. Which is what StackOverflow is all about.

Answer (score 15):

You can use -lang-c-c++-comments preprocessor to have both ANSI mode and C++-style comments.

```
gcc -Wp,-lang-c-c++-comments -c source.c
```

Comment: That's because it's actually a preprocessor flag, so you invoke it like: gcc -Wp,-lang-c-c++-comments -- not directly on the command line. However, if you really want ansi portability then you shouldn't have c++ style comments... :)

Comment: i think yours is the definitive answer.

Comment: I believe that this is no longer supported.  I cannot get it to work in GCC 4.2 or 4.4 on either Mac or Linux.  I can only find this reference in GCC's CPP manual (going back to version 2.9) "Note: Previous versions of cpp accepted a `-lang` option which selected both the language and the standards conformance level. This option has been removed, because it conflicts with the `-l` option." I cannot find a replacement.

Answer (score 3):

If you use `-ansi` only to check compatiblity, then the easiest might be to prepare a script or makefile target which copies the complete source tree into a "ansi" folder while patching away the // comments. In pseudo-bash:

```
SRC=main.c blip.c blip.h
cp makefile ansi-src/
for F in $SRC do
# does not handle // in string literals or /**/ comments!
sed 's/\/\/.*//g' < $F >ansi-src/$F
done
cd ansi-src
make CFLAGS=-ansi
```

If your SCC supports it, this could also be made into a commit-hook which builds the code automatically on a dedicated machine in ANSI mode after each commit and mails you a report about it.

Comment: Beware of trailing backslashes though when patching your sources.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid scripting up some kind of comment-rewrite utility (as Luther Blissett suggests) might be your only option here.  In modern versions of gcc, there doesn't seem to be any sort of compiler flag or CLI option that will enable C++-style comments when `-ansi` or `-std=c89` is used.

You might be able to get at what you want by approaching it from a different angle.  You may be able to compile with `-std=c99` and use compiler flags to *disable* the C99-specific extensions that you don't want (without knowing more about why exactly you need ANSI compliance, I can't recommend specific flags).

Answer (score -3):

You could automatically build a copy of the source with the comments stripped, and use that in your program.

E.g. [this](http://bash.cyberciti.biz/academic/sed-remove-c-cpp-comments/) looks promising

Answer (score -7):

C has had C++ style comments for nearly ten years now, maybe you should upgrade?

Comment: I think we are using gcc 3.x supplied by Wind River for 64bit embedded systems

Comment: That's what he's trying to do - upgrade from C89 to C89 with C++-style comments. Given that he said the target is an embedded system, it's unlikely that it has a C99-compliant compiler anyway. Even GCC doesn't implement C99.

Comment: Actually it turns out to be gcc 2.9!!

Comment: If the code will only ever need to be compiled on gcc of version 2.9+, there's not much point using the -ansi flag. That stops you using things that other C89 implementations might be lacking, but if that's not a requirement then consider just using the default mode, -std=g89, which does permit //.